# how to get alternating bottom-border colors for navigation

Tags: css, navigation, line, alternating

How can I get my navigation to look like this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSNHL.png

Here is my current code.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c239f1b541aa26d461b

I'm really just struggling with the line style. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working with the borders here:
http://jsfiddle.net/HAZKh/39/
The only thing is i set the color to be red for all of them, so if you want it to be different you need to have special border color style for nth-child style of the nav UL element

these are what i changed:

```
.header .menu-bar a {
  text-align:center;
  display:block; 
  color: #989898;
  margin: 0 auto
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none; 
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

and

```
.header .menu-bar li {
  float: left;
  border:medium #0F0;
  /* padding: 0 32px; */
  padding-left: 32px;
}
```

Comment: no problem, i didnt see it is marked as answer though :)